# Unable to Set Logging Level and Output in Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am unable to set Root Logger Option through properties file in Log4j. Below is how my properties file looks -

I have saved this file as log4j2.properties in the root of src folder.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I tried setting the rootLogger to ALL but, it doesn't work. However; if I set the Level to ALL through the method in my program it works. Example -

```
package com.nanwani;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LoggerTest {

    public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoggerTest.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        log.setLevel(Level.ALL);

    }

}
```

In addition, it seems it is not referring to my properties file at all however, if I delete this file then it does show ERROR message that - using default properties file as log4j2 file not found.

Comment: Your code doesn't log anything.

Comment: Hi Talex - I am showing the code where it logs something because, it is not working anyway. Can you suggest something?

Comment: I don't see `log.debug(...)` or something like this. What logging output you expect?

Comment: "I have saved this file as log4j2.properties in the root of src folder." Is 'the root of  src folder' on the classpath at runtime?

Comment: Hello Bharat. Is it a maven project?. If it's the case try to put that file in resources folder

Comment: Hi OscarBcn - It is not a maven project.
Hi Bradimus - I presume it is because, as I mentioned, if I delete the file, it tells me the log4j2 properties file not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. Log4j2 does not support configuration properties file as opposed to Log4j v1. New formats are XML, JSON, and YAML, see the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: Hi Bharat. I read under "Automatic Configuration", "6. If a test file cannot be located the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.properties on the classpath." Does using other format resolve your problem?

Comment: Log4j2 some time ago added support for properties file configuration files. The format is different from Log4j1, so as of 2.6.2 you cannot use a Log4j1 properties file to configure Log4j2. There is work in progress to make Log4j2 also support the old Log4j1 properties configuration syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the update Remko! And Luis - Yes, using Log4j2.xml file in the class path solves my problem.

Comment: So, is it a solution for your problem to use the xml format? And if so... can you write an answer to your question and mark it as a valid solution? That way other stackoverflow.com users will see it easily.

Answer (score 0):

The file log4j2.properties must be named log4j.properties (if you are using Log4j version 1) . And you have to log something using log.debug("message"). What about considering moving the file to the src/main/resources folder?

Comment: Hi Luis - Log4j.properties doesn't work. I'm not using version 1. As i mentioned earlier, I'm showing any logging code as it doesn't work anyway. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm checking a project I have here in my workspace and I see I'm using these imports: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager and org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger. Then I use private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("MyClass"); and works fine. I hope it helps you.